# Rails controller test error: count didn't change by 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm writing some models for a project. I have a `User.rb` class, that has the following attributes:

> - first_name: string
> - last_name: string
> - address_line_1: string
> - address_line_2: string
> - town: string
> - post_code: string
> - tel_no: string
> - email: string
> - password_digest: string
> - type:

I have a second model `Employee.rb` that inherits from `User.rb`.

Both `User.rb` and `Employee.rb` were scaffolded. `User` was scaffolded first, and `Employee` was scaffolded with the `--parent=User` option.

When running tests, I get the following error:

```
Failure:
EmployeesControllerTest#test_should_create_employee [filepath]:
"Employee.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 3
Actual :2
```

---

Here's the code that is failing in employees_controller_test:

```
setup do
  @employee = employees(:employee_one)
end

test "should create employee" do
  assert_difference('Employee.count') do
    post employees_url, params: { employee: { first_name: @employee.first_name, last_name: @employee.last_name, address_line_1: @employee.address_line_1, address_line_2: @employee.address_line_2, town: @employee.town, post_code: @employee.post_code, tel_no: @employee.tel_no, email: @employee.email, password_digest: "@employee.password_digest", type: @employee.type } }
  end

  assert_redirected_to employee_url(Employee.last)
end
```

---

Here are my employees fixtures, in employees.yml

```
employee_one:
  first_name: "Employee1"
  last_name: "Example"
  address_line_1: "3 High Street"
  address_line_2: "Flat 3"
  town: "Glasgow"
  post_code: "G15 9BL"
  tel_no: "0123847439"
  email: "employee1@employee1.com"
  password_digest: "password"
  type: "Employee"
```

---

I guess my `User.rb` is also important to include:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :first_name,      presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :last_name,       presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :address_line_1,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :address_line_2,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, :allow_nil => true
  validates :town,            presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :post_code,       presence: true, length: { maximum: 10 }
  validates :tel_no,          presence: true, length: { maximum: 14 }
  validates :email,           presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :password_digest, presence: true, length: { maximum: 256 }
  validates :type,            presence: true, length: { maximum: 15 }
end
```

---

I've been at this for 4 hours or so, and I think I just need a fresh pair of eyes.

If I go on `rails console --sandbox` and individually enter 2 users with User.create, and individually enter 2 Employees, there's no problem.

What's creating the error?

Comment: Did you tried to debug the response returned from making the `post` request and its status, You could do this my making `puts response` or something, I used to do this somehow with rspec gem, After running the test check the `rails server` terminal and see if there is an error or exception that prevent things to work fine.

Comment: Could you add the code for the `EmployeesController` as well?

Comment: Also have a look into the `log/test.log` file and see if there are any errors showing up there. Also copy (from the logfile) the params coming through... and look a few lines after that to see if there's eg an error telling you some params are not permitted.

Comment: I have figured it out thanks to @AmrAdel and SimpleLime. The permitted parameters in the EmployeesController were only 'type'. It seems that scaffolding with the --parent option, does not add every parameter from the parent class to the child class. Thus, every parameter was empty except 'type'. All I had to do was add the rest of the parameters to the permitted parameters in EmployeesController. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaffolding the `employee.rb` model with the `--parent=User` option, does not automatically add the inherited parameters from `user.rb` to `employee.rb`.

This meant that in the `employees_controller.rb`, the `employee_params` method, that defines the allowed parameters was:

```
def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:type)
end
```

Which meant that when the test was creating an entry in the Employees table, every parameter except `type` was not inserted.

I fixed it by changing `employee_params` to:

```
def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :address_line_1, :address_line_2, :town, :post_code, :tel_no      , :email, :password_digest, :type)
end
```

And now all tests pass.